# Python auto clicker, how to listen for mouse events

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

I can't figure out how to make auto clicks start when I press the left mouse button and stop when I release it. Maybe someone knows how to solve it?

Perhaps with the help of `pynput` it is not advisable to do this, but it is better to use `pyautogui`, or there are some other solutions.

```
# importing time and threading
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

# pynput.keyboard is used to watch events of
# keyboard for start and stop of auto-clicker
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode


# four variables are created to
# control the auto-clicker
delay = 0.277
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='+') #The left mouse button should be here
stop_key = KeyCode(char='-')


# threading.Thread is used
# to control clicks
class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):

    # delay and button is passed in class
    # to check execution of auto-clicker
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    # method to check and run loop until
    # it is true another loop will check
    # if it is set to true or not,
    # for mouse click it set to button
    # and delay.
    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)


# instance of mouse controller is created
mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


# on_press method takes
# key as argument
def on_press(key):
    # start_stop_key will stop clicking
    # if running flag is set to true
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
            print("click end")
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
            print("click start")

    # here exit method is called and when
    # key is pressed it terminates auto clicker
    elif key == stop_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I searched for a solution but didn't understand anything.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

It turned out that using the left mouse button when it is pressed is not the best solution, but rather not working.

You need to use an unoccupied key, in my case it is the middle mouse key. I replaced the function `on_press` with the function `on_click`, which was presented in the `pynput` documentation, but thereby lost the functionality of completing the script on the key.

Here is the code:

```
# importing time and threading
import time
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput import mouse


delay = 0.277
button = Button.left


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False


    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                muse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)


# instance of mouse controller is created
muse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if button == button.middle:
        if pressed:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
            print("click start")
        elif not pressed:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
            print("click end")


with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```